# This throws me string null is not assignable to type string error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I got the following code and it gives me error `Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

```
this.userId = authInformation.userId;
```

So I'm trying to check if `authInformation.userId` returns null and If it's null, do nothing, if it's not null `this.userId` should be set to `authInformation.userId`. And it still has an error and I don't know what's the error.

```
const usertypecheck = authInformation.userId;
this.userId = usertypecheck !==null ? "" : usertypecheck;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong, reverse the logic here from ,

```
this.userId = usertypecheck !==null ? "" : usertypecheck;
```

to

```
this.userId = usertypecheck === null ? "" : usertypecheck;
```

That should solve the problem.